# Conditions for the invertibility of $A \in M_n (F [X])$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Considering the following (from the book Algebra by Adkins and Weintraub):

[image]

I think there is a mistake in the $(2)$ of Example 2.19 : it must be $\det(A) \in F[X]^* = F[X] - {\{0}\}$, otherwise it must be true that for any $F_1[X] \in F[X] - {\{0}\}$ there exists $F_2[X] \in F[X] - {\{0}\}$ such that $1/F_1[X]=F_2[X]$; (which I think is true unless the polynomial is an infinite series). Am I right?

Simple detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units of $F[x]$ are precisely the elements of $F^\times$: a nonconstant polynomial's inverse in $F(x) = \operatorname{Frac}(F[x]) = \left\{\frac{p}{q}\mid p,q\in F[x],\,q\neq 0\right\}$ is no longer a polynomial. That is to say, $\left(F[x]\right)^\times = F^\times\neq F[x]\setminus\{0\}$. (So, the claim that "it must be true that for any $F_1[X] \in F[X] - {\{0}\}$ there exists $F_2[X] \in F[X] - {\{0}\}$ such that $1/F_1[X]=F_2[X]$" is incorrect. See below.)

**Claim:** Let $F$ be a field, and let $p\in F[x]$ be a nonconstant polynomial. Then $p$ has no inverse in $F[x]$; i.e., $p\not\in\left(F[x]\right)^\times$.

**Proof:** We will show that $pq$ can never be $1$ for any $q\in F[x]$. If $q = 0$, certainly $pq\neq 1$. So suppose that $q\neq 0$. Then
$$
\deg(pq) = \deg p + \deg q > \deg q\geq 0,
$$
because $p$ is nonconstant (and hence $\deg p\geq 1$) and $q\neq 0$, so that $\deg(pq)$ and $\deg q$ are well-defined and $\deg q\geq 0$. However, $\deg 1 = 0$, which implies that $pq$ cannot equal $1$ for any choice of $q.$

Comment: So if entries of a matrix are noncostant polynomials such that A (Adj (A) ) has at least one nonconstant polynomial then A is not invertable? Thanks

Comment: @L.G. $A(\textrm{Adj}(A)) = \det(A) I$, so all entries of $A(\textrm{Adj}(A))$ are either $0$ or $\det(A)$. Your statement is true, but more complicated than it needs to be. If $A$ is a matrix with entries in $F[x]$, then $A$ is invertible iff $\det(A)$ is a nonzero constant in $F$. Keep in mind, there are examples of matrices with entries in $F[x]$ which are not invertible, but all entries are constant, and there are examples of matrices with some nonconstant entries which *are* invertible, and the more general statement I've made applies to both these situations as well.